# Accessing Backbone view this from a nested function call

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, leaflet

I'm trying to do the following:

```
Backbone.View.extend({
    ...

    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        // "this" should be the view but is
        // the function like normally in closures
        this.doSomething();
    },

    geoJsonSynced: function () {
        this.geojson = L.geoJson(
            this.collection.geojson(),
            {
                onEachFeature: this.onEachFeature
            }
        );  
    }


    ...

});
```

I thought it'd be a different case because onEachFeature is a property of a view but clearly that is not the case here. I can't think of a way to do this properly. Normally with closures I just do var that = this, but in this case I can't get the "that" into the scope.

I tried to get that into the scope by:

```
geoJsonSynced: function () {
    var that = this;
    this.geojson = L.geoJson(
        this.collection.geojson(),
        {
            onEachFeature: this.onEachFeature
        }
    );  
}
```

I guess I am doing it wrong.

Currently I am doing it (in my own opinion) in a very terrible way by having a global variable and doing the following in onEachFeature:

```
onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    var view = globalVariable.someView;
    view.doSomething(); 
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

EDIT:
It was easier to fix than I thought:

```
geoJsonSynced: function () {
    var onEachFeature = _.bind(this.onEachFeature, this);
    this.geojson = L.geoJson(
        this.collection.geojson(),
        {
            onEachFeature: onEachFeature
        }
    );  
}
```

Thanks code runner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `_.bindall()` , the same problem is discussed very clearly [here](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2011/08/18/understanding-bind-and-bindall-in-backbone.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do the same using jquery

```
geoJsonSynced: function () {
        this.geojson = L.geoJson(
            this.collection.geojson(),
            {
                onEachFeature: $.proxy(this.onEachFeature,this)
            }
        );  
    }
```

Docs - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/